# R filtering a dataframe for a proportion of columns meeting criteria

Tags: r

I'm sure the answer to this question is out there already, but I can't find it, since I'm a beginner at R and don't know what search terms to use.

I want to retrieve the rows in a data frame where a given proportion of the columns meet a criteria. For example, 2/3 columns >1.3.

Here is what I have so far:

```
a<-c(1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5)
b<-c(1.3,1.4,1.5,1.6,1.7)
c<-c(1.5,1.6,1.7,1.8,1.9)
data<-data.frame(a,b,c)
data`

   a   b   c
1 1.1 1.3 1.5
2 1.2 1.4 1.6
3 1.3 1.5 1.7
4 1.4 1.6 1.8
5 1.5 1.7 1.9


c<-function(x) (length(x[(x>1.4)]))>=(2/3*ncol(data))
d<-apply(data,1,c)
result<-data[d,]
result

   a   b   c
3 1.3 1.5 1.7
4 1.4 1.6 1.8
5 1.5 1.7 1.9
```

This works, but I feel like there must be a simpler way, or that the function could be written differently? I'm still trying to properly undestand this whole function-thing.

Of course, in reality my dataframe would have alot of columns.

/Grateful beginner

Comment: I guess it should be better to work with a matrix with this kind of data and operations. "+", "-", "<", "==", "apply", "rowSums", "[i, ]" etc either convert to a "matrix" every time you call them or are slower than when used on "matrix". So, you could, just, use `as.matrix` at front and save time in subsequent operations.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe (Should be more efficient as `rowSums` is vectorized and saves the need in using `apply` loop)

```
data[rowSums(data > 1.4) >= 2/3*ncol(data),]

##     a   b   c
## 3 1.3 1.5 1.7
## 4 1.4 1.6 1.8
## 5 1.5 1.7 1.9
```

Or if you prefer a function, could try

```
myfunc <- function(x) x[rowSums(x > 1.4) >= 2/3*ncol(x), ]
myfunc(data)

##     a   b   c
## 3 1.3 1.5 1.7
## 4 1.4 1.6 1.8
## 5 1.5 1.7 1.9
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to give another alternative to David's answer. You can use the `mean` function on a vector of logical values in R to return the percentage of `TRUE` values in the vector.

Create the data

```
a<-c(1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5)
b<-c(1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.6, 1.7)
c<-c(1.5, 1.6, 1.7, 1.8, 1.9)
data<-data.frame(a, b, c)
```

A function to return a logical vector indicating if the values are above the threshold

```
gt <- function(x, threshold){
  tmp <- x > threshold
  return(tmp)
}
```

An example using the first row of the `data.frame`

```
gt(data[1,], 1.4)
```

If you take the sum of the logical vector it returns the number of `TRUE` instances:

```
sum(gt(data[1,], 1.4))
# [1] 1
```

and if you use the `mean` function it returns the percentage of positive instances:

```
mean(gt(data[1,], 1.4))
# [1] 0.3333333
```

Using that you can use David's approach:

```
index <- apply(data,1, function(x) sum(gt(x, 1.4)) >= 2/3 * length(x))
```

or you can use the percentage via the `mean` function.

```
index <- apply(data,1, function(x) mean(gt(x, 1.4)) > 0.6)
```